# Every 5 min cron job between specific time (Windows Server 2008 and batch file)

Tags: windows, batch, php, windows-task-scheduler

Previous colleague set up `cron` job every 5 min for 24 hrs.
Now I need to modify this only running between 7am to 7pm.

I had never learned `cron` job so I googled and tried but it didn't work.

Task Scheduler is set as below

- Begin the task
  On a schedule
- Settings
  One time
- Advanced settings
  Repeat task every 5 minutes for a duration of Indefinitely
  Stop task if it runs longer than 30 minutes
  Enabled

And I modified the batch file from

C:\PHP\php.exe -f C:\path\cron.php five-mins

to

*/5 7-19 * * * C:\PHP\php.exe -f C:\path\cron.php five-mins

Even I added */5 7-19 * * * to batch file, it doesn't work.

It would be appreciative if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance and thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390617/windows-task-scheduler-run-only-during-window-of-time

Comment: > Big Chris, thanks for the suggestion I had a look and this could be one of the solution however this time I will use RedGrittyBrick's batch file coding. Anyway thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows native job scheduler is not configured the same way as Unix/Linux `cron`,

You cannot change the scheduling by editing the contents of a batch file.

You have limited options in the Task scheduler

[image]

You could alter that batch file to exit early if the time of day is outside a specific range.

[An answer in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14282788/477035) suggests

```
set "currentTime=%Time: =0%"
set flag=false
if %currentTime% geq 07:00 if %currentTime% leq 19:00 set flag=true
if %flag%==true (
   # your existing commands
   # go here
)
```

Comment: > RedGrittyBrick, thank you very much for your explanation and details. Yes it works great! I never thought I could use coding for batch file as I hadn't self-learned it yet. Again, I appreciated it Thank you!